# How can I get the size in pixels of the space below the text of a textview? (not the bottom padding)

Tags: android, textview, android-canvas

bottomPadding returns 0 and is set to 0, but my textview still has padding below it's text.

[image]

I am trying to draw text on a canvas at the same height as the textview is from its parent but for some reason Paint.drawText() ignores the extra padding at the bottom.

Since the canvas object has its origin a the bottom-left corner, I have to provide the the y position of the text from below.

I can't do the following:

```
yPosition = textview.bottom + ((rectbounds.getHeight() - textViewHeigth)/2)
```

This is because the size of the space on top of the text is bigger than the bottom space.

Removing the extra space from the textview would also solve my problem. However, I already tried setting includeFontPadding to false, and setting padding to 0, but neither work.

Comment: If you write a tall character like Î is the space still bigger in top than bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you put a 'g', 'p', 'y', or 'j' in your TextView?  Each of these characters has a [descender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender), and the metrics for the font will always allocate space for this feature of many scripts.  This is to allow for the fact that multiple lines of flowing text ought not be crammed into each other.

If you really need to get the size of a font's descender, you can use a [Paint](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) object, load it with a [Typeface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) and ask for its [descent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#descent()).  But a TextView I don't think is going to change the way it renders its lines for you.  If you must ignore the descent, draw your own text in a custom view.

Comment: YOU BEAST OF A DEVELOPER!!!! I had no idea that the descent() method gave me this info. THANKS!!! I had to use:

`textView.SetIncludeFontPadding(false);`

and now

`yPosition = text.Bottom - paint.Descent();`

works perfectly.